# Pick the first timestamp before a gap, but the last one of the day if there is no suitable gap

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a TIMESTAMP column:

```
dates
2021-06-24 05:47:05
2021-06-24 09:47:05
2021-06-24 13:47:05
2021-06-24 17:47:05
```

I want to pick the first timestamp of a given day that is 3 hours or more  before the next next timestamp of that same day.

```
expected output:

2021-06-24 05:47:05
```

**However**, if there is **no** timestamp that is more than 3 hours before any other (on that given day), then the last timestamp of that day should be returned.

Comment: I removed the `sql-server` tag since your question is about PostgreSQL rather than Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Updated my answer since my first one failed to tackle the `if there is not time with 3 hours or more difference then last time should be picked` - it should work now!

Comment: `3 hours apart from next time` . "Next" time means "later" time or "closest" time (sooner or later). Please clarify. `date is always same.` means you query for *one* given day? And always disclose your version of Postgres, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a completely revised answer which is much more efficient than the previous one. The old answer can be seen either by viewing the edit history or as a footnote at the bottom of this post.

A fiddle for all the code below is to be found at the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e946232b92f00bc5247d8efc0735ebd6).

So, we have our test table:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  the_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);
```

Populate it - added records for a day with no gaps > 3 hours:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES


('2021-06-23 05:47:05'::TIMESTAMPTZ),     -- NO gaps > 3 hours on this date!
('2021-06-23 07:47:05'::TIMESTAMPTZ),
('2021-06-23 09:47:05'::TIMESTAMPTZ),
('2021-06-23 11:47:05'::TIMESTAMPTZ),
('2021-06-23 13:47:05'::TIMESTAMPTZ),
('2021-06-23 14:47:05'::TIMESTAMPTZ),  
('2021-06-23 16:47:05'::TIMESTAMPTZ),  
('2021-06-23 17:47:05'::TIMESTAMPTZ),
    

('2021-06-24 05:47:05'::TIMESTAMPTZ),  -- TWO gaps > 3 hours on this date

                                      -- 1st gap > 3 hours

('2021-06-24 09:47:05'::TIMESTAMPTZ),

                                      -- 2nd gap > 3 hours

('2021-06-24 13:47:05'::TIMESTAMPTZ),

('2021-06-24 14:47:05'::TIMESTAMPTZ),  -- added for testing
('2021-06-24 16:47:05'::TIMESTAMPTZ),  -- added for testing


('2021-06-24 17:47:05'::TIMESTAMPTZ);
```

And (demonstrating the logic) then ran the following SQL:

```
SELECT
  the_date::DATE AS dat, 
  the_date AS td, 
  LEAD(the_date) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY the_date::DATE 
           ORDER BY the_date ASC) AS l_td,
  LEAD(the_date) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY the_date::DATE 
            ORDER BY the_date ASC) - the_date AS diff  -- for demonstration
FROM                                                   -- purposes - see diffs
  test                                                 -- > 3 HOUR - 2 on 24/06
ORDER BY dat, td;
```

Result:

```
       dat                      td                   l_td   diff
2021-06-23  2021-06-23 05:47:05+01  2021-06-23 07:47:05+01  02:00:00
2021-06-23  2021-06-23 07:47:05+01  2021-06-23 09:47:05+01  02:00:00
2021-06-23  2021-06-23 09:47:05+01  2021-06-23 11:47:05+01  02:00:00
2021-06-23  2021-06-23 11:47:05+01  2021-06-23 13:47:05+01  02:00:00
2021-06-23  2021-06-23 13:47:05+01  2021-06-23 14:47:05+01  01:00:00
2021-06-23  2021-06-23 14:47:05+01  2021-06-23 16:47:05+01  02:00:00
2021-06-23  2021-06-23 16:47:05+01  2021-06-23 17:47:05+01  01:00:00
2021-06-23  2021-06-23 17:47:05+01  NULL                    NULL        
2021-06-24  2021-06-24 05:47:05+01  2021-06-24 09:47:05+01  04:00:00
2021-06-24  2021-06-24 09:47:05+01  2021-06-24 13:47:05+01  04:00:00
2021-06-24  2021-06-24 13:47:05+01  2021-06-24 14:47:05+01  01:00:00
2021-06-24  2021-06-24 14:47:05+01  2021-06-24 16:47:05+01  02:00:00
2021-06-24  2021-06-24 16:47:05+01  2021-06-24 17:47:05+01  01:00:00
2021-06-24  2021-06-24 17:47:05+01  NULL                    NULL        
14 rows
```

We've used the [`LEAD()`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-lead-function/) window function. [Window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-window.html) are extremely powerful and I would **stongly** urge you to put some effort into  learning how to use them - they will repay that effort many times over!

- It provides a comparison between the value of `the_date` and the value following it according to the criteria in the `ORDER BY` - you can do lots of clever stuff by varying the `ORDER BY` clause in the `LEAD()` function itself - that and varying other parameters can be seen [here](https://joshuaotwell.com/lead-window-function-with-examples-in-postgresql/).
- The `PARTITION BY the_date::DATE` clause is to give separate results for every  date that is in your dataset. Note in particular the NULLs - you can't have a LEAD that spans days thanks to the partitioning, so the LEAD value for the last timestamp on any given day will always be `NULL` - this relates to the requirements - see below.

Also, note that `NULL` minus anything is `NULL` (same for `NULL` plus...) - we say that `NULL`s "propagate".

So, now we run this SQL:

```
WITH leads AS
(
    SELECT
      the_date::DATE AS dat, the_date AS td, LEAD(the_date)
          OVER (PARTITION BY the_date::DATE) AS l_td
    FROM
      test
)
SELECT DISTINCT ON(dat)
    dat AS "The date", td AS "Gap start or last ts"
FROM leads
WHERE l_td - td > INTERVAL '3 HOUR'
   OR l_td IS NULL
ORDER BY dat, td;
```

Result:

```
The date    Gap start or last ts
2021-06-23  2021-06-23 17:47:05+01
2021-06-24  2021-06-24 05:47:05+01
```

The desired outcome! But, what's going on? From [here](https://www.geekytidbits.com/postgres-distinct-on/):

> PostgreSQL has a really interesting and powerful construct called
> SELECT DISTINCT ON. No, this is not a typical DISTINCT. This is
> different. It is perfect when you have groups of data that are similar
> and want to pull a single record out of each group, based on a
> specific ordering.

or, put another way (from the same link):

> With DISTINCT ON, You tell PostgreSQL to return a single row for each
> distinct group defined by the ON clause. Which row in that group is
> returned is specified with the ORDER BY clause.

Or from the PostgreSQL documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-select.html):

> SELECT DISTINCT ON ( expression [, ...] ) keeps only the first row of
> each set of rows where the given expressions evaluate to equal. The
> DISTINCT ON expressions are interpreted using the same rules as for
> ORDER BY (see above). Note that the “first row” of each set is
> unpredictable unless ORDER BY is used to ensure that the desired row
> appears first. For example:
>
> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT ON (location) location, time, report
>     FROM weather_reports
>     ORDER BY location, time DESC;
> ```
>
> retrieves the most recent weather report for each location. But if we
> had not used ORDER BY to force descending order of time values for
> each location, we'd have gotten a report from an unpredictable time
> for each location.
>
> The DISTINCT ON expression(s) must match the leftmost ORDER BY
> expression(s). The ORDER BY clause will normally contain additional
> expression(s) that determine the desired precedence of rows within
> each DISTINCT ON group.

As you can see, this (like window functions) is obviously a very powerful tool in the PostgreSQL programmer's arsenal and is **well** worth taking the time and the effort to learn.

An interesting alternative approach would be to use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function, if say you want the first two gaps or the last record, as follows:

```
WITH leads AS
(
    SELECT
      the_date::DATE AS dat, the_date AS td,
      LEAD(the_date)
          OVER (PARTITION BY the_date::DATE) AS l_td
    FROM
      test
),
gaps AS
(
    SELECT
      dat, td,
      ROW_NUMBER()
          OVER (PARTITION BY dat ORDER BY td) AS rn
    FROM leads
    WHERE (l_td - td > INTERVAL '3 HOUR')
      OR (l_td IS NULL)
)
SELECT
    dat, td
FROM gaps
WHERE rn <= 2  -- NOTE 2!
ORDER BY dat, td;
```

Result:

```
       dat                      td
2021-06-23  2021-06-23 17:47:05+01
2021-06-24  2021-06-24 05:47:05+01
2021-06-24  2021-06-24 09:47:05+01
```

Note that we **now** have two records for 2021-06-24.

Finally, and just for the record, the original solution:

```
WITH long_gaps AS
(
  SELECT dat, MIN(td) AS gap
  FROM
  (
    SELECT
      the_date::DATE AS dat, the_date AS td, LEAD(the_date) OVER (PARTITIION BY the_date::DATE) AS l_td
    FROM
      test
  ) AS t1
  WHERE l_td - td > INTERVAL '3 HOUR'
  GROUP BY dat
),
short_gaps AS
(
  SELECT the_date::DATE AS dat2, MAX(the_date)
  FROM test
  WHERE the_date::DATE NOT IN (SELECT dat FROM long_gaps)
  GROUP BY dat2

)
SELECT dat AS "The date", gap AS "Gap start or last ts" FROM long_gaps
UNION 
SELECT * FROM short_gaps
ORDER BY 1;  -- parameter 1 which ORDERs BY the first field in the query
```

Result:

```
  The date     Gap start or last ts
2021-06-23   2021-06-23 17:47:05+01
2021-06-24   2021-06-24 05:47:05+01
```

A performance analysis of the 3 solutions is given at the bottom of the fiddle - it shows that the `DISTINCT ON` solution is significantly more performant than the others - however the `ROW_NUMBER()` has the potential to be more flexible! However, a word of warning - a performance analysis on a very small dataset on  a server over which we have no control, nor any idea of what's happening elsewhere is potentially flawed - I would advise that you benchmark with reasonable datasets on your own hardware.

In future, when you are asking questions of this nature, could you provide a fiddle with sample data covering all of your cases - i.e. in this case, where there are gaps and where there are not. This reduces the possibility of error and eliminates duplication of effort - help us to help you. Also, please **always** include your version of PostgreSQL.

Comment: Nice, but it misses the requirement in the last line of the question to fallback to the last timestamp if there are no 3+ hour gaps:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=006acfbe4a277b9b6e2ef0d5437dafd2  I couldn't think of an elegant way to add that to this query.

Comment: @gwaigh - couple of nice new solutions introduced - you might want to take a look given your previous interest - deffo worth a look! :-)

Comment: You found the elegance that I had been hoping for.